# Como incluir uma ação no botão de cadastrar com HTML5?

Tags: html, html5, formulário

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
<form action="paginas/login.php">
    <p id="log">Usuário: </p> <input id="cmpG" type="text" name="usuario"/>
    <p id="log">Senha: </p> <input id="cmpG" type="password" name="senha" size=8 maxlength=8/>
    <p id="log">A senha deve conter 08 caracteres (alfanumerico)</p>
    <!-- Barra de botões -->
    <div id="barra">
        <input id="bnt" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        <input id="bnt" type="reset" value="Limpar"/>
        <BUTTON >Cadastrar</BUTTON>
    </div>
</form>
```

Bom, não sei como fazer o botão de cadastrar, tentei com `input` e do tipo `submit`, mas ele vai para a página `login.php` também, como fazer com que ele vá para outra página?

Comment: E você esperava que ele fizesse o que? Ele não vai para outra página magicamente. Ou tem que estar em outro `form` ou tem que criar uma ação personalizada para ele.

Comment: Fosse para uma página `cadastro.php` mas não sei se isso é possível, estou apenas tentando fazer rs, sem referência nem nada.. A ideia seria ter duas páginas como destino para o form, se o usuário apertar o botão X ele ir para página X e se apertar Y ir para página Y, ambos passando parâmetros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tens duas opções:

- mudar o action com JavaScript e fazer submit via JavaScript
- mudar o action com o [`formaction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-formaction) adicionado no HTML5 (IE9+)

De qualquer das maneiras podes ter dois botões submit:

```
<div id="barra">
    <input class="bnt" name="" type="submit" value="login"/>
    <input class="bnt" type="submit" value="cadastrar"/>
    <input class="bnt" type="reset" value="Limpar"/>
</div>
```

Repara que mudei também `id` para `class` pois IDs têm de ser únicas.

## usando JavaScript:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var inputDiv = document.getElementById('barra');
var urls = {
    cadastrar: 'paginas/cadastro.php',
    login: 'paginas/login.php'
};
function verificarDestino(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
    var tipo = e.target.value;
    var url = urls[tipo];
    form.action = url;
    alert(url); // só para verificar
    form.submit();
}
inputDiv.addEventListener('click', verificarDestino);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zveq0y4/

## usando HTML5

```
<div id="barra">
    <input class="bnt" type="submit" value ="Login" formaction="paginas/login.php"/>
    <input class="bnt" type="submit" value ="Cadastrar" formaction="paginas/cadastro.php"/>
    <input class="bnt" type="reset" value="Limpar"/>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zveq0y4/2/

Deste modo o próprio elemento input re-escreve o `action` do form.

#### Nota:

Na minha resposta uso `input` mas se quiseres usar `button` a lógica é a mesma e o `formaction` usa-se da mesma maneira também.

Answer (score 4):

Ou você tem que fazer:

```
<form action="paginas/login.php">
    <p id="log">Usuário: </p> <input id="cmpG" type="text" name="usuario"/>
    <p id="log">Senha: </p> <input id="cmpG" type="password" name="senha" size=8 maxlength=8/>
    <p id="log">A senha deve conter 08 caracteres (alfanumerico)</p>
    <!-- Barra de botões -->
    <div id="barra">
        <input id="bnt" type="submit" value="Login"/></a>
        <input id="bnt" type="reset" value="Limpar"/>
    </div>
</form>
<form action="paginas/cadastrar.php">
    <BUTTON >Cadastrar</BUTTON>
</form>
```

Ou usa um evento `onclick` para dar uma ação personalizada nele. Aproveitando seu próprio código seria algo assim:

```
<BUTTON onclick="window.location.href='paginas/cadastrar.php'">Cadastrar</BUTTON>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/ActionButton.js).

Talvez você queira fazer de outra forma mas te dei um exemplo de forma simplificada.

Comment: Se tiveres 2 forms ele não vai enviar os dados da outra, no segundo caso envia o form vazio.

Comment: @Sergio sim, claro, mas o que ele quer é chamar uma página de cadastro que não é o mesmo formulário mesmo. No fundo é até o mais correto. Ter um botão dentro de um `form` mas não usar os dados dele está semanticamente errado, apesar de funcionar. E o meu entendimento é este, Se ele quer enviar os dados, de fato a solução de envio baseado no `click` é a adequado, por isso eu coloquei as duas. A sua resposta, apesar de correta e mais completa, não usa o `<button>` que é o que ele quer usar.

Comment: Ok, entendo melhor a tua lógica. Nesse caso ele podia ter simplesmente uma âncora para a página cadastrar. Juntei à minha resposta info sobre `button` que é igual, bem visto, obrigado.

Comment: Concordo, mas usei o que ele queria.